# Install Zebra GK420D on WIn 7

Tags: windows-7, zebra-printer

I am not able to get this printer working on Win 7. It is connect via USB. I've downloaded and run the Zebra Setup Utilities. When installing the printer, I select
- ZDesigner GK240d
- Port USB001 
and it proceeds without error.

There is an option for ZDesigner GK240d (EPL). What is EPL?

Then I open Printer Tools and select Print Configuration Label. Nothing happens.  I try printer others ways but nothing happens.
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: EPL Eltron programming language, you dont want this,

Comment: Thanks, glad I didn't chose that then

Comment: Download and read this PDF from Zebra>>>>>https://support.zebra.com/cpws/docs/zebradesigner/zebradesigner_driver_installing_with_windows7.pdf

Comment: Thanks, doing that now. It says "After entering a valid IP address ...". What do I enter for an IP address? I have to do this for a USB printer?

Comment: I tried 192.168.0.26 has a partially arbitrary attempt. This did not work.